# re.sub is replacing the text in my file with blanks. Not sure why

Tags: python-3.x

Recently tried some revisions to see if my I could trace down the issue and see if my regex string was even being matched. No luck on the match, however I am not certain it's all correct. Top code is most recent.

```
import os
import re

progNumber = 1
text_to_replace = re.compile("^BOWL_PROG6_14G$")
replace_string = 'Bowl_Prog1'


def sub_ftext(file_path='W:\\BOWL PROGRAMS 14G'):
    old_text = text_to_replace
    count = progNumber
    for d_name, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for f_name in files:
            f_path = os.path.join(d_name, f_name)
            if f_name.endswith('.ls'):
                with open(f_path) as txt:
                    s = txt.read()
                    for line in txt:
                        if text_to_replace.search(line):
                        # Substitute the contents
                            new_text = replace_string + str(count)
                            s = re.sub(old_text, new_text, s)
                            # Write it back into the file
                            with open(f_path, "w") as txt:
                                txt.write(s)
                            count += 1
                            print(s)
                            print(old_text)

     # for text in text_to_replace:
     #        print(text)
        # dirnames = set(os.path.join(d_name, d) for d in dirs)
        #     # Traverse subfolders
        # if dirnames.startwith('BOWL-'):
        #     for subs in dirnames:


sub_ftext()
```

`The program finds the string I am looking for but replaces it with nothing in every file.

```
import os
import re


os.chdir('W:\\BOWL PROGRAMS 14G')
progNumber = 1
text_to_replace = re.compile("^BOWL 14G$")
replacement = ("Bowl_Prog_14G" + str(progNumber))


for d_name, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for f_name in files:
        f_path = os.path.join(d_name, f_name)
        if f_name.endswith('.ls'):
            with open(f_path) as txt:
                for line in txt:
                    s = txt.read()
            #s = s.replace(text_to_replace, replacement)
            with open(f_path, "w") as txt:
                txt.write(s)
                print(re.sub(text_to_replace, replacement, line))
                progNumber += 1
```

Comment: I have tryed writing the replacement variable both with and without ()

Comment: Do you intend to replace the contents and writing them back to the file? Right now `print(re.sub(text_to_replace, replacement, line))` is only printing the substituted content but you're still writing the original content back to the file with `txt.write(s)`

Comment: Yes I intend to replace the contents and write the new contents back to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import re


def sub_text(file_path):
    os.chdir(file_path)
    prog_number = 1
    text_to_replace = re.compile("BOWL_PROG[0-9]*_14G")
    for d_name, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for f_name in files:
            replacement=("Bowl_Prog" + str(prog_number))
            f_path = os.path.join(d_name, f_name)
            if f_name.endswith('.ls'):
                with open(f_path) as line:
                        ls = line.read()
                with open(f_path, "w") as line:
                        ls = re.sub(text_to_replace, replacement, ls)
                        line.write(ls)
                        print(line)
                        prog_number += 1
                        print(prog_number)
                        print(replacement)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_text(r"W:\\BOWL PROGRAMS 14G")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor touch-ups to your existing code. You don't really need to substitute the contents line by line, hence I have removed that line.

```
import os
import re

progNumber = 1
text_to_replace = re.compile("^BOWL_14G$")

def sub_ftext(file_path, text_to_replace, progNumber):
    for d_name, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for f_name in files:
            replacement = ("Bowl_Prog_14G" + str(progNumber))
            f_path = os.path.join(d_name, f_name)

            if f_name.endswith('.ls'):
                with open(f_path) as txt:
                    sl = txt.read()
                # Substitute the contents
                sl = re.sub(text_to_replace, replacement, sl)
                # Write it back into the file
                with open(f_path, "w") as txt:
                    txt.write(sl)

                progNumber += 1

    # Traverse subfolders
    dirnames = set(os.path.join(d_name, d) for d in dirs)
    if dirnames:
        for subs in dirnames:
            sub_ftext(subs, text_to_replace, progNumber)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_ftext(r'C:\Documents\TestFolder', text_to_replace, progNumber)
```

**Edit:** If you need to traverse the subfolders as well, one way to do it is to wrap the lines above up into a function, which you can then call recursively. There are probably other ways to do it as well

Comment: This is kind of confusing for me. The .ls file that i am trying modify is saying it has been modified in notepad, but nothing changes.

Comment: actually it's one root directory. Within that root directory there multiple subdirectories and within each of those there is are 2 more subs and one of those sub_folders houses the .ls files that I need to get to.

Comment: @Robotics101 Updated my answer to allow the traversal of subdirectories. You will have to do a small refactor on your code to call the function and feed it with the path of the directory that you want to process if you decide to use this

Comment: So for an update. I have tryed the way that you posted by wrapping the code into a function and it did not seem to work as long the bottom part was there. When I comment that out  however and just call the function it partially works but it deletes the whole program. I don't remember this being this complicated when I did stuff like this in C#. But it's a learning curve and hopefully I figure this out soon. I do however appreciate the help you have given me. You have given me some much needed insight. DO you think it could be possible that my issue is in my reg expression?

Comment: Also at one point it was reading the whole textfile but would not change anything. Almost like the regex did not hit a match. You have any idea how I could test the regex string. See if it works mabey.

Comment: I just wrote so would see the above comments

Comment: Possibly something is wrong with the write statement because I have recently done some reg expression tests and the Bowl_Prog hits just fine it seems.

Comment: @Robotics101 I've updated my answer with the full script to perform the steps that you need. For troubleshooting, to check if it's reading the intended files / catching the lines that you're targeting, it's always useful to dump some lines out onto the console

Comment: I have tried dumping some lines to the terminal. Oddly it seems to traverse through the directory. Read each individual .ls file, because it does print it to the console. However it does not change the program information. I will try it the this way. The way you put up and see if it works out for me.

Comment: @Robotics101 If your file content is being replaced with blanks then it's most likely your regex.

Comment: I figured this out last night but didn't really have time to post it. It turns out the 2 main issues with the code was the regex was wrong and the sub was in the wrong place. The sub need to be in the write function and not the read. Also after removing the beginning and end line tags off the regex string and adding a range of numbers and a wild-card it works like a charm. Your answer definitely help me get there though. Thanks for the help.